# Field calculation- Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

I am developing a script to calculate the values of two fields (C and D) based on value of field A (It is a Point feature):

```
A C D
0.2 1 1
0.2 1 2
0.2 1 3
0.4 2 1
0.5 3 1
0.5 3 2
```

So the idea is

```
n = 1
k =0
while i < endrow
{
if a[i]==a[i+1]
c[i]=n
d[i] = k+1
if a[i] < a[i+1]
i=i+1
k=0
c[i]=n+1
d[i]= k+1
}
```

Not sure - cursor can help me. But is there any way for such comparison and update the column?

Thanks

adding another complication- field E which has the maximum D for every unique A or C; so it will be:

```
 A C D  E
0.2 1 1 3
0.2 1 2 3
0.2 1 3 3
0.4 2 1 1
0.5 3 1 2
0.5 3 2 2
```

Because my ultimately goal is to keep only D ==1 and label the remained points with C and E (say: there are 3 points at location 1)

```
A C D  E
0.2 1 1 3
0.4 2 1 1
0.5 3 1 2
```

Right now appears, I have to run another combination of search and update cursor after calculation of C and D but if there is any other concise and sleek approach! If I will figure it out - I will post it here!

Comment: The methods described at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16752 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27047 may solve this problem for you.  (I'm pretty sure *exactly* this question has been asked and answered on this site, but I have been unable to find the duplicate.)

Comment: Finished the task but instead of keeping the max value for D, assign a boolean variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without indents, I'm not sure what you mean your code to do. From the table you gave, it looks like you want **C** to count the number of unique values up to that point, and **D** to count the number of times the current value of **A** has recurred (so once is 1, twice in a row is 2, etc.) If this is right, and if the values in **A** are ascending, this should work (I'm at home so I can't check with arcpy, unfortunately):

```
import arcpy

# create the cursor and populate the C and D fields of the
# first row.
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor('TableNameHere')
row = cur.next()
last = row.getValue('A') # the last value in field A

row.setValue('C', 1)
row.setValue('D', 1)
cur.updateRow(row)

run = 1 # how many values in this run
count = 1 # how many runs so far, including the current one

# the for loop should begin from row 2, since
# cur.next() has already been called once.
for row in cur:
    current = row.getValue('A')

    if current == last:
        run += 1
    else:
        run = 1
        count += 1
    row.setValue('C', count)
    row.setValue('D', run)
    cur.updateRow(row)

    last = current

# release the layer from locks
del row, cur
```

Substitute the path of your table for **TableNameHere** and the correct field names for **A**, **B** and **C**, of course.

Answer (score 3):

This is a rough cut at your problem; I haven't tested it out, but the logic should generally be what you need:

```
import arcpy

tbl = r'path\to\db.mdb\table'

#-Get field objects in table
fields = arcpy.ListFields(tbl)

#-Create an empty list to hold row data in memory
data = []

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(tbl)
for row in rows:
    #-Create an empty dictionary to store each row
    d = {}
    for f in fields:
        d[f.name] = row.getValue(f.name)
    data.append(d)
del row,rows

n = 1
k = 0
i = 0
less_than = False
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(tbl)
for row in rows:
    if less_than:
        #-update rows c and d with the appropriate values
        row.c = n+1
        row.d = k+1
        less_than = False
    else:
        if row.a == data[i+1][a]:
            #-update rows c and d with the appropriate values
            row.c = n
            row.d = k+1
        elif row.a < data[i+1][a]:
            #-set flag and skip to the next row
            less_than = True
    i+=1
    rows.updateRow(row)
del row,rows
```